# Recyclerview continue where you left off

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to continue where I left off (my last item position) on recyclerview when I restart the application
like twitter or 9gag.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use navigation component? If so, you can use "keep_state_fragment"